# CSS Absolute-Center

Tags: css

I have a header box that spans the width of my screen.  I have a slider image that goes in this section.  The problem is that I need my image absolutely centered which it does not do  when the screen size shrinks.  Instead it loads from the left margin and fills to the right.  Only the right side of my image is cropped.  I actually need the image to be centered and cropped on all sides evenly as the screen shrinks.

I found a [solution here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/), but I can't get it to work for me.  I was hoping someone here understands this code and can help me adjust mine.

Here is how my code is written right now.

```
#rt-header {
    height:502px;
    margin-top:-132px;
    position:relative;
}

#rt-header .rt-container {}

#text_slider{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    margin:0;
    background:url(../images/system/loading.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat #171b1e;
    height:502px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#text_slider.loaded{
    background:#171b1e;
}
#text_slider li{
    width:100%;
    background:none !important;
    list-style:none;
    z-index:0;
    width:100% !important;
    height:100% !important;
    display:none;
}
#text_slider li img{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:0;
    min-width:1400px !important;
}
```

Any insight you can provide will be much appreciated.

Comment: if you vertical-align your image aside an inline-box or pseudo element with a text align and finally virtually gives it no size with negative margin, you can get something very close to absolute center. here a test with different img sizes http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/full/Hdpku Is this something alike you are looking for ?

Answer (score -1):

put a fixed width to the `div` containing what you want to center (lets say `width:700px` for example) and then use `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` on the same `div`